# CSS Not Working After Published

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got errors (*Not Showing CSS*) in my project after deployed to server,  it works fine in local .I found same questions like this and tried them all but still im unable to solved .

**what i have tried :**

[Style bundling not working after IIS deployment (MVC 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946685/style-bundling-not-working-after-iis-deployment-mvc-4)

[BundleConfig not rendered after publish in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909761/bundleconfig-not-rendered-after-publish-in-iis)

[ASP.NET MVC Bundle not rendering script files on staging server. It works on development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270834/asp-net-mvc-bundle-not-rendering-script-files-on-staging-server-it-works-on-dev)

[ASP.NET MVC framework 4.5 CSS bundles does not work on the hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081255/asp-net-mvc-framework-4-5-css-bundles-does-not-work-on-the-hosting)

[Why is my CSS bundling not working with a bin deployed MVC4 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985431/why-is-my-css-bundling-not-working-with-a-bin-deployed-mvc4-app)

**Error:**

[image]

**CSS Shows In Server Like This**

```
<link href="/PMTEST/bundles/font-awesome/css?v=iW7LN24NnEoW62YKSq4wmEVP62Z-QPaYj8Wc4pAfkQA1" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/PMTEST/bundles/animate/css?v=TS_TayB91ibtNEIEuFyRTY4MKruiSouKnZGvXM9wZzc1" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/PMTEST/bundles/bootstrap/css?v=fGVgsGSw8MzJqPS1QdcxeRW2yrw4tez5BLZBchwK_HE1" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/PMTEST/bundles/icon?v=Xt7dqD5fI6gBI3RBoPWSt1nfcmgT1f4bGcYcuT_dBno1" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Bundle Config in my application**

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/font-awesome/css").Include(
                      "~/Vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

**In My Layout Page i used Bundle like**

```
   @Styles.Render("~/bundles/font-awesome/css")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved , just add

> BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

in `BoundalConfig`

Answer (score 3):

For the fonts part you can use this in your `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
  {...}
 <staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/font-sfnt" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

And for the other bundle make sure the bundle reference path is not an actual file path, because if it is then IIS will handle it as a static file not MVC as a bundle.

Comment: I have used font part in web.config , but issue is same

Comment: Can you try the bundles without the `new CssRewriteUrlTransform()` ?

Comment: Yes but same issue